# How to set max-width of css grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid and it looks and works great when there are many items. However, when there are 1, 2 or 3 items the cards are stretched.

I tried to set the `max-width` to each card but the width of the columns remain the same. Is there a way to set `max-width` of each column? I need to use it only when there are 3 columns or less. (I am very new to css grid)

```css
.big-container {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting minmax in pixel values, like `minmax(100px, 200px)`. This means that the grid columns can be maximum 200px wide.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it but it puts a big gap between the boxes when there are many of them.

Comment: Do you want 4 columns in one row? why not just define it like that? It looks like your container is responsive and your columns are made to fit inside of that grid no matter the amount of divs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting `grid-template-columns` to `auto-fill`, will prevent cells to stretch in case of column < 4

see below snippet:

```css
.big-container {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```